# Setup priority on Azkaban parallel flows/depedencies

Tags: azkaban

I'm using Azkaban 3.4.1 and one of my flow has more than 30 dependencies. Some dependencies are takes more longer than another. So, I want to prioritize these flows to started before another flows. (because the running thread is limited)

Currently the number of parallel execution is limited with `flow.num.job.threads` which is `10` by default. I tried increase that property and make sure the long process started right away, but the cpu get very high, so I am not sure that is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this fork https://github.com/hanip-ss/azkaban/releases/tag/3.4.2.

I can now add `job.priority` value in job properties file.